# Merge two dataframe on the basis of two column, while considering nan values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to merge two dataframe -  **Lifetime_df** and  **Input_DataFrame2**. The final  **Lifetime_df**  should contain everything which it had, but replaced with count of  **Input_DataFrame2**  for matching columns ['Identifier_column', 'lifetime']

```
Lifetime_df

    Identifier_column  lifetime count
0      138122               1     1
1      138122               2     1
2      138122               3   NaN
3      138122               4   NaN
4      138122               5     0
5      138122               6     1
6      138122               7   NaN
7      138122               8     0
8      138122               9     1
```

```
Input_DataFrame2

    Identifier_column  lifetime count
0      138122               1     1
1      138122               2     4
2      138122               6     1
3      138122               9     1
```

Desired Output:

```
Lifetime_df

    Identifier_column  lifetime count
0      138122               1     1
1      138122               2     4
2      138122               3   NaN
3      138122               4   NaN
4      138122               5     0
5      138122               6     1
6      138122               7   NaN
7      138122               8     0
8      138122               9     1
```

The following command's output doesn't satisfy the requirement

```
Input_DataFrame3 = pd.merge(Lifetime_df, 
                                Input_DataFrame2, 
                                how='left', 
                                on=[Identifier_column, lifetime])

Lifetime_df['count'] = Input_DataFrame3['count_y']
```

Getting:

```
Lifetime_df

    Identifier_column  lifetime count
0      138122               1     1
1      138122               2     4
2      138122               3   NaN
3      138122               4   NaN
4      138122               5   NaN
5      138122               6     1
6      138122               7   NaN
7      138122               8   NaN
8      138122               9     1
```

Comment: how can your command work? I doubt on=[Identifier_column, lifetime]) are defined variaables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the good old `merge` and `fillna`:

```
Input_DataFrame3  = Lifetime_df.merge(Input_DataFrame2, 
                                      on=['Identifier_column', 'lifetime'], 
                                      how='left', 
                                      suffixes=['_x', ''])

Input_DataFrame3['count'] = Input_DataFrame3['count'].fillna(Input_DataFrame3['count_x'])
Input_DataFrame3 = Input_DataFrame3.drop(columns='count_x')

   Identifier_column  lifetime  count
0             138122         1    1.0
1             138122         2    4.0
2             138122         3    NaN
3             138122         4    NaN
4             138122         5    0.0
5             138122         6    1.0
6             138122         7    NaN
7             138122         8    0.0
8             138122         9    1.0
```

---

Or inspired by YOBEN's answer, `pd.concat` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
key_cols = ['Identifier_column', 'lifetime']
pd.concat([Input_DataFrame2, Lifetime_df]).drop_duplicates(key_cols).sort_values(key_cols)

   Identifier_column  lifetime  count
0             138122         1    1.0
1             138122         2    4.0
2             138122         3    NaN
3             138122         4    NaN
4             138122         5    0.0
5             138122         6    1.0
6             138122         7    NaN
7             138122         8    0.0
8             138122         9    1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

We can try `concat` then `groupby` with `first`

```
df=pd.concat([Input_DataFrame2,Lifetime_df]).\
      groupby(['Identifier_column','lifetime'])['count'].first().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas-dataframe-combine-first):

```
cols = ['Identifier_column', 'lifetime']
Input_DataFrame2.set_index(cols)\
   .combine_first(Lifetime_df.set_index(cols)).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Identifier_column  lifetime  count
0             138122         1    1.0
1             138122         2    4.0
2             138122         3    NaN
3             138122         4    NaN
4             138122         5    0.0
5             138122         6    1.0
6             138122         7    NaN
7             138122         8    0.0
8             138122         9    1.0
```